# nocheck within admin file for pkgadd still asks questions

Tags: solaris

I place the following into an admin file called `noask`

---

mail=
instance=overwrite
partial=nocheck
runlevel=nocheck
idepend=nocheck
rdepend=nocheck
space=nocheck
setuid=nocheck
conflict=nocheck
action=nocheck
basedir=default

---

Then run `pkgadd -a noask -d sed-4.1.5-sol10-x86-local` - yet am still queried for:

'Select package(s) you wish to process'

Is there a way around the questioning without doing an "echo yes" at the front?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You do not tell what package to install from the package datastream which might contain more than one package (although it doesn't in your case).

This should work:

```
pkgadd -a noask -d sed-4.1.5-sol10-x86-local '*'
```

Comment: or you could do 

echo "yes" | pkgadd -a noask -d sed-4.1.5-sol10-x86-local

Comment: indeed but the question is precisely asking how to avoid this "echo yes | ..." workaround.

Comment: good point must have not had my brain completely in gear when typing this comment.

Comment: @jlliagre This does not work for me when I install OpenCSW:

root@solaris:~# pkgadd -a noask -d http://get.opencsw.org/now '*'
## Downloading...
..............25%..............50%..............75%..............100%
## Download Complete
pkgadd: ERROR: no package associated with <*>
root@solaris:~#

It works if I explicitly pass the package name instead of an asterisk

Comment: @AndriyYurchuk I guess it is because you are passing an URL, not a file as the question is about. It should work if you do it in two steps  like 'wget .../now && pkgadd -a noask -d now "*"'